# How can I change the background color of the text in the terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, gnome-terminal

When I do an operation like

```
ls -l
```

Several results are shown with an unpleasant background color, how could I change so that this unpleasant background color changes?

Comment: IMG:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IjoUSE_Kty-1DhatSOKhKdJvjNwzobqX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It's basically because the permission of the file. Your folder has green background and blue foreground which means that dir is other-writeable(o+w) and not sticky.
If you want to know the color represent what the file type is, you can print `dircolors` to a file, like this:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

Back to your problem, to change the color of that dir you can remove the write permission of the others group:

```
chmod -R o-w redentor
```

You surely want to remove the background color of all dirs inside `redentor` too, so `-R` helps you do that recursively.

Comment: Ty!! @linshup !